# Mongodb limit access to user related documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, nosql

I was checking if there is a way to restrict users access to specific documents of a collection maybe the ones that belongs to that user only , but the only way i found for similar thing is to create restricted views using pipline.

is it logical to have for x number of users x number of views created from each collection ?! Is this a good practice in mongo world ?
If no then please guide me what am I missing

Comment: MongoDB does not provide access control on document level. Either you deploy it on the application level or by views.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit so is it logical if I have 1 million user yo have 1 million view of specific collection?

Comment: This looks like you should better implement this at application level.